# Slow count (with join) query on MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Well, I just arrived in a project and I do not understand much about SQL tuning.

I saw a process that takes a long time to run and I started to look at some queries this process do.

One of the queries is a count with joins that takes up to 10 minutes to run.

```
select count(rtvp.id) from rel_transaction_voucher_product rtvp
        join `transaction` t on t.id = rtvp.transaction_id
        join voucher v on v.id = rtvp.voucher_id
        where v.situation_code = 'YYYYY' 
        and t.transaction_type_code = 'XXXX'
        and t.expiration_date < curdate()
```

Rows of each table in the query:

- rel_transaction_voucher_product: 1.7 million
- transaction: 1.6 million
- voucher: 1.3 million

Explain result:

```
id|select_type|table|partitions|type  |possible_keys                                                                               |key                                               |key_len|ref                       |rows  |filtered|Extra      |
--+-----------+-----+----------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------+------+--------+-----------+
 1|SIMPLE     |t    |          |ref   |PRIMARY,transaction_type_code,transaction_id_type_date_IDX                                  |transaction_type_code                             |38     |const                     |815765|   33.33|Using where|
 1|SIMPLE     |rtvp |          |ref   |uk_transid_voucherid_productid,voucher_id,rel_transaction_voucher_product_transaction_id_IDX|rel_transaction_voucher_product_transaction_id_IDX|38     |voucherprd.t.id           |     1|   100.0|           |
 1|SIMPLE     |v    |          |eq_ref|PRIMARY,fk_voucher_situation_code                                                           |PRIMARY                                           |38     |voucherprd.rtvp.voucher_id|     1|   45.46|Using where|
```

I realize that if I remove `and t.expiration_date < curdate()` the query returns in about 30 seconds, but this condition is extremely important.

Is there anyway to have this query run faster?

Comment: Try adding an index on `(transaction_type_code, expiration_date)`

Comment: @Barmar. . . Wow! It dramatically increases the performance, took around 3 - 5 seconds to run. Genius! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an index on the columns being used in the `WHERE` condition.

```
ALTER TABLE transaction ADD INDEX (transaction_type_code, expiration_date);
```

If you already have an index on just `transaction_type_code`, you won't need it any more, since it's a prefix of this new index.